# Ansys Norton creep power law constants?

Tags: structural-engineering, ansys-workbench, creep

I’m trying to learn creep analysis in Ansys, and am currently working on deriving creep constants, specifically C1, C2, and C3 for the Norton Power Law.

I understand that the equation is usually shown in 2 ways:

$$\dot\epsilon = A \sigma^n t^m$$

or

$$\dot\epsilon = A \sigma^n \exp\left(-\dfrac{Q}{RT}\right)$$

Which form does Ansys use? I can’t seem to find an answer in any of the manuals or anywhere online.

For example, I know solid works uses the first form, where $C_1 = A$, $C_2 = n$, and $C_3 = m$.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www2.me.rochester.edu/courses/ME204/nx_help/index.html#uid:id1212733 it uses creep strain = $A \sigma^n t^m$ where $A$ = C1, $n$ = C2, $m$ = C3.

Answer (score 0):

I think the original Norton-Bailey is for the [creep strain](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267504748_The_Application_of_the_Norton-Bailey_Law_for_Creep_Prediction_Through_Power_Law_Regression) $\epsilon(t)$, whereas ANSYS uses a variation for the creep strain rate $\dot{\epsilon}(t)$;

$$\dot{\epsilon}(t) = C_1\cdot \sigma^{C_2}\cdot t^{C_3}\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{C_4}{T}\right)$$

You can checkout [Creep page in ANSYS Help Material reference](https://ansyshelp.ansys.com/account/secured?returnurl=/Views/Secured/corp/v222/en/ans_mat/rate.html): "4.5.5.1. Implicit Creep Equations" - this one is with time hardening (2<sup>nd</sup> row in the table).